# Showing Comma separated values inside Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

**What I have**

I have a gridview bounded  to a some Datasource. Inside that i have added another column ("Resources") explicitly bounded to another datasource.

**Code.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TFSId" HeaderText="TFSId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TFSId" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsBillable" HeaderText="IsBillable" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IsBillable" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Estimate" HeaderText="Estimate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Estimate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Resources">
             <ItemTemplate  >
             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="TextBox1_PopupControlExtender" runat="server"
                                 Enabled="True"  TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
                                 PopupControlID="Panel1" OffsetY="22">
                     </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="116px" Width="145px" 
                         BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" Direction="LeftToRight"
                         ScrollBars="Auto" BackColor="#CCCCCC" Style="display: none">
                             <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
                                 DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="UserId"
                                 DataValueField="UserId" AutoPostBack="True"
                                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                             </asp:CheckBoxList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:42HNetDbConnectionString %>"
                                 SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [UserId] FROM [Resources]">
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
       </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**What I want:**

I have been able to display all the names of resources as soon as user click the textbox. user can select as many resources as he/she wants. I need to achieve following:

1.I want to show the comma separated names of all the resources as soon as the user clicks on the checkboxlist. For that purpose I have created onselectedindexchanged event.

2.I also want some idea that how to remember what user has selected last time as it is not remembering.

**What I tried:**

**Code Behind**

```
   protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        /*
        string name = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                name += CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text + ",";
            }
        }
        TextBox1.Text = name;*/
    }
```

The real **problem** is i'm not able to access CheckBoxList inside onselectedindexchanged event.

[How to access textbox, label inside update panel from code behind using asp.net web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096077/how-to-access-textbox-label-inside-update-panel-from-code-behind-using-asp-net) seems to be less helpful.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got it:

**Code Behind**

```
 protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            UpdatePanel up1 = GridView1.Rows[j].FindControl("updatepanel1") as UpdatePanel;
            TextBox tb1 = up1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
            CheckBoxList cb1 = up1.FindControl("CheckBoxList1") as CheckBoxList;

            string name = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < cb1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (cb1.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    name += cb1.Items[i].Text + ",";
                }
            }
            tb1.Text = name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string strVendorId = string.Empty;
            var vender = new StringBuilder();
            var vendorcollection = cmbVendorId.CheckedItems;
            foreach (var item in vendorcollection)
                vender.Append(item.Value + ",");
            strVendorId = vender.ToString();
            if (strVendorId != "")
            {
                strVendorId = strVendorId.Remove(strVendorId.Length - 1, 1);
            }
```

U can use this code as a reference code for comma separate

Comment: Thanks for reply  but actually i'm not able to access cmbVendorId inside the onselectedIndexchanged event.That's the real problem.

Comment: cmbvendorId is the name of My combobox...put ur combobox name in place of cmbvendorId

Comment: u can write CheckBoxList1.CheckedItem inplace of  cmbVendorId.CheckedItems;

Comment: That's what i'm trying to say that i'm not able to access  CheckBoxList1 inside the onselectedIndexchanged .Thanks!!